# RxJS 6+ Type 'Observable' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Trying to get a filtered array of values from an observable I got the following error:

> Type 'Observable' must have a 'Symbol.iterator'
>   method that returns an iterator.

Code:

```
export class ItemsService {

  orderItems: OrderItem[] = [];
  orderItemsUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/order-items/';

  getOrderItemsFromHttp(selectedOrderNumber): Observable<OrderItem[]> {
    const tempArr = [];
      const orderItems = of (this.http.get<OrderItem[]>(`${this.orderItemsUrl}`)
      .subscribe(res => {
            this.orderItems = res;
      }) );

    for (const orderItem of orderItems) {                        <--- Error here
        if (orderItem.orderNumber === selectedOrderNumber) {
          tempArr.push(orderItem);
        }
    }
    return of(tempArr);
  }  
}
```

If I modify the following

```
for (const orderItem of orderItems) {
```

to

```
for (const orderItem of [orderItems]) {
```

error disappears but the property **orderNumber** is no more recignized, and the intellisens says:

> Property 'orderNumber' does not exist on type 'Subscription'

So how can I fix it, please ?

Comment: This is all some very confused RxJS. What’re you trying to accomplish

Comment: describe in some detail what you're trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to me you're looking for this:

```
  getOrderItemsFromHttp(selectedOrderNumber): Observable<OrderItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<OrderItem[]>(`${this.orderItemsUrl}`).pipe(
      map(orderItems => orderItems.filter(oi => oi.orderNuber === selectedOrderNumber))
    );
  }
```

for this to work you'll need to import the `map` operator:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: That provides a good alternative, I had to replace some variables in my code, but at the end it worked very fine, thanks a lot Bryan.

Comment: great, glad i could help out

Comment: all looks fine to me. I'd add some logging and make sure your backend is actually returning what you expect.

Comment: can't really say why without knowing what kind of modifications you've made.  make sure you have all of the code, including the return statement,

Comment: It worked, so I marked the question as answered and removed the comments that may be not relevant to others, please kindly do the same from your side, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend separating the way you connect and look for business logic data, so that changing from http to SignalR for example does not mean changing your business logic.

Create another service that its task is only to search for elements using http request, your ItemsService would use that service to search the data.

You don't need to rebuild the array

```js
@Injectable ({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestService {
config: Config; // Your URLs
   getItems () {
     return this.http.get <OrderItem []> (this.config.itemURL, {note: 'response'});
   }
}

@Injectable ()
export class ItemsService {

  orderItems: OrderItem [];

constructor (private restService: RestService) {
}

getItems () {
   return new Observable ((observer) => {
    restService.getItems (). subscribe ((items) => {
      observer.next (items);
    });
  });
}

}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of wrapping the rest call in another observable?

Comment: Consume it from a component or wherever you want asynchronously. Basically multilayer programming, to make http requests in the same component is to ignore 30 years of software engineering

Comment: you can already consume it where ever you want asynchronously without wrapping it in an entirely superfluous observable. `return restService.getItems()` is pretty much identical functionally and architecturally without a bunch of unneeded extra stuff going on. and while yes, you want to separate concerns, you don't gain much here by creating a rest service and an items service, the items service already isolates the responsibility of getting items via http. a simple pass through is just layers and complexity for the sake of layers and complexity.

Comment: I agree 100% with you, but it is just an example, imagine a more complex app, various communication protocols with the SOAP, REST, WebSocket backend. Multilayer programming is healthy

Comment: the http service in angular already provides that functionality. I don’t see any gains to a rest service wrapping it to provide semantic access to resources that individual resource services already provide, regardless of complexity. A more complex app also doesn’t justify a random observable wrapper around an observable